# Domain of Composite Functions: $\text{ domain of } g(f) = \text{ domain of } f$ and $ \text{ domain of } f(g) = \text{ domain of } g$

Tags: functions

I have functions $f$ and $g$. However, the domain of $f(g)$ is not the same as the domain of $g$.

- $f = \{ (1,2), (2,3), (3,4) \}$
- $g = \{ (1,2), (2,0), (3,5), (4,3) \}$
- $f(g) = \{ (1,3), (4,4) \}$
- $g(f) = \{ (1,0), (2,5), (3,3) \}$

However, the domain of $f(g)$ does not equal the domain of $g$. So is $f(g)$ not defined in this case? Or is it a function with a smaller domain than $g$?

Comment: For short, $f(g)$ is still a function but with a smaller domain. Note that the function $f$ has domain $\{1,2,3\}$ and hence you have to make sure that whatever comes out of $g$ is in this set, to allow that $f(g)$ makes sense. Perhaps someone will elaborate on this for you, this is just some intuition.

Answer (score 2):

The domain for a composite function $f(g)$ is not just the domain of $g$ but rather it is equal to: $$D_{f(g)}=\{x \in D_{g}\vert g(x) \in D_{f}\}$$ which means the domain of $f(g)$ is equal to the domain of $g$ if and only if $(\forall x \in D_{g} \implies g(x) \in D_{f})$ which isn't true for this case. We have $(1,4 \in D_g \implies g(1)=2,g(4)=3 \in D_{f})$